# How to exclude a repository while installing updates using apt-get

Tags: 12.04, apt

I generally do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But I do not wish to update Google Chrome i.e. I don't want to install updates from
`http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/` repository.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the corresponding line(s) in `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **System Settings...** > **Software & Updates**, select **Other Software** tab and follow the instructions from the next immage:

[image]

Generally, if you don't want that a particular package to be updated, you can block it by running next command in terminal:

```
echo "[packagename] hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: I think you use XNeur or similar program... It replaced -- sequence with — sign.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! I had thought that unticking the repo. in software-center wouldn't make any difference in installing via terminal, but it wasn't so.